# My typehead field pushes down on my nav

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a type head search field in my navbar, similar to the one google has so when I type a letter the results form under it in a drop down list fashion. But when the results populate the dropdown list, they push down on my nav so that it stretches to the length of my results. Not a css specilaist at all. I tried doing something with the z-index but that didn't work. And a few other things I tried to tweak but nothing worked How can I get this to work. Heres navbar code my code.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
 <div class="container">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'posts:list'  %}">HEiGHTS</a>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="{% url 'posts:list'  %}">Home</a></li>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">Admin</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'posts:create' %}">Create</a></li>
    {% endif %}
  </ul>

  <form method="GET" action="{% url 'posts:search-page' %}"  class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">

    <div class="form-group">{% csrf_token %}
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" id="search" placeholder="search" value="{{ request.GET.q }}">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">search</button>

    <ul class="list-group" id="search-results" style="margin: 5px 0 0 0; width: 172px">

    </ul>

  </form>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

all guidance is welcome thanks.

Comment: can you provide full html code so that can check and provide solution

Answer (score 0):

The typeahead dropdown box which contains the results needs to have absolute positioning for it to be able to overlay other content.